# Wrong attributes displaying in layered navigation

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, filter

Don't know if anyone can help. Using Magento 2.3.2

We sell plants on our site, and I have set up different attribute groups for different types of plants - shrubs, veg, flowers, fruit, and herbs. Some share attributes, whilst others don't.

This is an example of my issue.

Euphorbia plant has 'shrub' attribute group assigned to it - soil PH, hardiness, height, flower colour, foliage colour.

When on the shrub category 'Ideal for' shows in the layered navigation - this is an attribute in the 'flower' attribute group, not the 'shrub', and when you click on it it brings up options that click through to the Euphorbia, which doesn't even have this attribute in its group and does not have it assigned. What could be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: are there any other products in the shrub category which have been assigned to the flower attribute group?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, everything in the shrub category has got 'shrub' attributes. Normally I can tell if something has the wrong attributes set, as I get too many options in the layered navigation (as in this case), but everything that is appearing in the 'flower' attributes has 'shrub' attributes set.